# How to properly add firebase messaging to webapp using webpack?

Tags: webpack, firebase-cloud-messaging, aurelia

I'm trying to get FCM to working using webpack. I'm using the following code:

```
//firebase.ts
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/functions';
import 'firebase/messaging';

const firebaseConfig = {
 <my cofigs>
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// firebase.firestore().settings({timestampsInSnapshots: true});

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export default firebase;
```

```
//firebase-messaging-sw.js (the service worker is being installed in the chrome dev)
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.5/firebase-messaging.js');


firebase.initializeApp({
   <my config>
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

```
//app.ts

export class App{
async attached(){
   const token = await firebase.messaging().getToken() 
     alert(token)
}
}
```

But everytime I call getToken() I get:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active.
```

I tried to run it locally and in a production enviroment (https) without any success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @Luis is there any update about it?

Comment: In my case, there was a promise-polyfill@7.1.0. I updated it to version 8 that's it.